# Cucumber/Gherkin Data Table flow with multiline arguments

Tags: cucumber, gherkin

I'm a bit confused on how the Data Table info is parsed outside of a precondition when using multiline arguments. In short I have a function that sends an **id** and a **user** variable, and the server will respond with the user variable and its status (online/offline). Here's an example:

```gherkin
Given that the user has access to the server

When sending a server_info request with the following parameters:
"""
id = <id>
user = <user>
"""
| id     | user  |
| 0      | userA |
| 1      | userB |
| 2      | userC |

Then the server will return the <user> and status
```

But the same can also be written as:

```gherkin
Given that the user has access to the server

When sending a server_info request with the following parameters:
"""
id = <id>
user = <user>
"""
Then the server will return the <user> and status
   Examples:
   | id     | user  |
   | 0      | userA |
   | 1      | userB |
   | 2      | userC |
```

My understanding is that in the first example the flow is something like this:

1. You send 3 consecutive server_info requests
2. Only after all 3 are sent, you verify them
3. The scenario runs only once

While in the second example the flow is:

1. You send a single server_info request
2. You verify that specific request
3. The scenario runs two more times, for a total of three times

The reason I'm asking is because the server will respond with a pair of variables on the screen, but any new requests will overwrite the previous ones. In short, the previous values will no longer be displayed on the screen, only the most recent ones, so I'm forced to verify what's on the screen before a new request is sent. If my understanding of the first example is correct, then at the end of that **When** loop, I will verify the response only for the last pair (id = 2 and user = userC), since the previous two have been overwritten. If this is true, then I shouldn't use a Data Table, but instead I'd need to use the 2nd example with a Scenario Outline to verify all the pairs.

So what I'm asking, is my understanding of the flow correct? I know this can be circumvented if you store the variables in the implementation phase, but I'm wondering about the flow in particular. Appreciate all the help!

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood your questions right.

If you use smth like:

```
Given User does this
|opt1|opt1-1|
|opt2|opt2-2|
```

it is just a step with a datatable, it is useful, for example, when you fill into the form (you provide some data and fill all at the same time)

Examples are being used in Scenario Outline. The logic is very similar to the DataProvider if you're aware of it.
So it means the scenario will be executed the same time as many rows you have in the table. If 2 rows - whole scenario will be executed twice. First time it will pick up the first row of the values, the next time - the second row etc.